# Eclipse made files empty

Tags: windows, eclipse

Just about an hour ago, I decided to switch my workspace folder in eclipse. So I created a new folder, moved all project folders to the new workspace folder and set this folder as the workspace folder in eclipse. Obviously, I had to re-import the projects, so I clicked import, selected the project and unchecked the copy to workspace checkbox because they were already in my workspace, but this gave me an error. So I tried again now checking the copy to workspace checkbox (I thought it could do no harm) and I didn't get an error. However, when my workspace loaded I got a lot of error and I noticed that eclipse had emptied all my project files! All files were still there, but all the data was gone: the files were 0 bytes.
I do have a back-up from most of my projects, but there's one project I hadn't backed up yet, so my question is: is there any way to recover the projects?

Comment: I don't think eclipse did that, I think you did. Just get your projects from your backup or source-control, and you'll be fine. I'm sure you have backup and/or source-control? Dropbox is free, and so is bitbucket. There's no reason *not* to use these services if you value your work.

Comment: Wow... why didn't you just rename your workspace folder or create a copy? Then you don't have to reimport. Have you tried browsing "local history" in eclipse?

Comment: @Axel where do you find local history?

Comment: @Merlin See greg's answer. But it seems you have already tried.

Comment: @Merlin: Next time just copy your complete wrokspace to the new location. Try it out, and if it works, you can delete the old one. I often copy my workspace to a new location when a bunch of local changes have piled up that are not ready for check-in, and because of a production problem have to roll back to the last checked-in state for maintenance (sometimes I wish we'd use another VCS...).

Comment: @Axel, yeah, this won't happen to me again, that's for sure. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @323go I just had it happen to me. Good thing I was using dropbox, but then again the issue happened because I was using dropbox in the first place. Eclipse puts out resources and lock files, so if you have Eclipse running on both machines that use dropbox, it will at some point in time start deleting folders/replacing them with empty files. I'm not sure what caused in exactly, but I know I'll now avoid having my workspace directly shared on dropbox with another of my computers.

Comment: I encountered the same problem today. Did you solve it? Can you please share your solution?

Comment: @vickey unfortunately no, I couldn't solve it. I tried a recovery tool, but it was already to late

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt it... My guess is Eclipse tried to copy the projects from and to the same folder, so it started by creating the folders, which replaced the existing ones with the new (empty) ones. Try looking into your bin, but I doubt there's a way to recover them without the use of a special recovery tool. I've never tried any personally, but that's your best chance IMO.

Comment: unfortunately my bin was empty, I'll try a recovery tool

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't really hoping for that :P

Comment: I have used recuva and it's definitely an awesome tool! I've been able to recover some of the project's files with it, but unfortunately not the java-files. Thanks anyway for your help, this is the correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the Project and select `Restore from Local History...`. Eclipse will show you any backups it has of the project files.

Comment: It says: the chosen option is not enabled